# WPA2 wifi access works in Mac but not windows

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, macbook-pro, wpa2

I have a macbook with windows installed in bootcamp. When I'm at the office, I can connect to our WPA2 enterprise wifi very easily in Mac osx, but windows can't. I suppose it has something to do with domain restrictions placed on our lan by the IT department, because to my knowledge, I have entered all the settings exactly right, but windows fails to connect and advises me to contact the administrator.

Does anyone know of anything I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested, Windows didn't have the right certificates installed, and IT had to copy them from another workstation to get my WiFi working.

Comment: Windows isn't the problem here. It's non-consumer friendly IT security protocols. (common in business)

Answer (score 1):

You should really contact your IT department with this problem. They know all the nuances of your wireless setup and can troubleshoot this problem right on the spot.

Comment: Problem is, it's my personal laptop, and they don't allow private laptops on their network. But they haven't given me a corporate one yet, and I have to get on with my job

Comment: @Erik - You will have to talk to them as the reason its not working, we cannot help you, bypass the restrictions imposed by your employeer.

Comment: @Erik You should talk to your manager or HR or whoever hired you. They do not allow personal equipment on their network, yet they have not provided you with necessary tools to do your job. So either IT will have to make an exception for your personal laptop or provide with a corporate one. Otherwise I think you are risking your employment status.

Answer (score -1):

I've been trying for a few weeks to connect my MacBook Pro to my uni wifi network (WPA-2 Enterprise). 
After a few attempts, I finally solved the problem and connected to the network.

Here's what I did :

1. Open network and sharing center
2. Go to the wireless network that u want to connect (WPA-2 Enterprise)
3. Right click > properties > security
4. Security type : choose no authentication (open)
   encryption type : none
5. It might have added (2) at the back of the network. Afterwards, just connect to that wifi network

Works like a charm :)